# DES Encryption works only with hard-coded BitArray but fails when reading .txt file

Tags: c#, arrays, encryption

I know this may seem like a vague question but I need some help from someone who knows about DES en c#.

I have a project that does DES Encryption manually without the use of any built-in libraries from the .NET framework. This is very important so I don't need any recommendations like use this library of that extension :)

I have been following this example: [The DES Algorithm Illustrated](http://orlingrabbe.com/des.htm) and everything works fine, after the 16 iterations I get the result as illustrated on that site.

I think the issue lays within my conversion from `String` to `List<BitArray>` because when following the example from the site I hard-coded the message and key value into a `BitArray`. Although when creating a new `BitArray` with a `byte` as value it turns the values around meaning the most significant bit is on the left hand side but all my code is adjusted to that.

I know it's a lot of code but keep in mind that this code does work if I use the hard-coded bits found on [this](http://orlingrabbe.com/des.htm) site.

Here's how I get the `List<BitArray>`:

```
private List<BitArray> splitFileIntoBlocksOf8Bytes()
{
    String bericht; //Nog niet van toepassing, maar legt het principe van feedback weer ;)

    List<BitArray> lstByteBlocks = splitByteArray8(Streamers.getFileInBytes(strPathForSourceFile));

    if (lstByteBlocks.Count == 0)
        bericht = "Het bestand dat u gekozen heeft is een leeg bestand";

    return lstByteBlocks;
}

//NOTICE how I turn each byte array around and revers the BitArray so it matches the logic found on the site!
private List<BitArray> splitByteArray8(byte[] arrBytes)
{
    List<BitArray> lstChunks = new List<BitArray>();

    byte[] chunkOfBytes = new byte[8];
    try
    {
        for (int byteAdded = 0; byteAdded < arrBytes.Length; byteAdded += 8)
        {
            Array.Copy(arrBytes, 0 + byteAdded, chunkOfBytes, 0, 8);
            Array.Reverse(chunkOfBytes);

            lstChunks.Add(Arrays.ReverseBitArray(new BitArray(chunkOfBytes)));
        }
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        BitArray addedBits = new BitArray(64);
        chunkOfBytes = new byte[8];
        int bitsToAdd = (int) Convert.ToInt32(64 - (Math.Ceiling(arrBytes.Length % 8.0) * 8));
        for (int bitAdded = 0; bitAdded < (arrBytes.Length * 8 - bitsToAdd); bitAdded++)
        {
            addedBits[bitAdded] = true;
        }
        Array.Copy(arrBytes, (arrBytes.Length - ((64 - bitsToAdd) / 8)), chunkOfBytes, 0, ((64 - bitsToAdd) / 8));

        lstChunks.Add(new BitArray(chunkOfBytes));
        lstChunks.Add(addedBits);
    }

    return lstChunks;
}
```

And here's the iterations code (each block goes through this function:

```
//lstEncodedFile = new List<byte[]>();
BitArray arrBlock = (BitArray)((object[]) args)[0];
BitArray arrPremutedBlock = initialPremutation(arrBlock, Arrays.InitielePremutatieArray);

BitArray arrLeftBits = new BitArray(32);
BitArray arrRightBits = new BitArray(32);
BitArray arrTempLeft;

for (int bitCounter = 0; bitCounter < 32; bitCounter++) 
{
    arrLeftBits.Set(bitCounter, arrPremutedBlock.Get(bitCounter));
    arrRightBits.Set(bitCounter, arrPremutedBlock.Get(bitCounter + 32));
}

int intStartIteratie = 0, intStopIteratie = 16, intStapIteratie = 1;
if (cryptType == CryptType.DECRYPT)
{
    intStartIteratie = 15;
    intStopIteratie = -1;
    intStapIteratie = -1;
}

for (int intIteratie = intStartIteratie; intIteratie != intStopIteratie; intIteratie += intStapIteratie) // 15 iteraties
{
    arrTempLeft = arrLeftBits;
    arrLeftBits = arrRightBits; //Li = R(i-1)
    arrRightBits = arrTempLeft.Xor(feistel.getFeistelResult(Arrays.ExpandBitArray(arrRightBits), intIteratie)); // Ri = L(i-1) XOR f(Ri, K(i+1))
}

BitArray arrIterationResult = new BitArray(64);
for (int bitCounter = 0; bitCounter < 32; bitCounter++)
{
    arrIterationResult.Set(bitCounter, arrRightBits.Get(bitCounter));
    arrIterationResult.Set(bitCounter + 32, arrLeftBits.Get(bitCounter));
}

byte[] byteResult = new byte[8];

BitArray arrResult = initialPremutation(arrIterationResult, Arrays.LaatstePremutatieArray);
arrResult.CopyTo(byteResult, 0);
lstCodedFile.Insert(intBlockCounter++, byteResult);
```

If you can't spot any errors yet, here's the feistel function:

```
public BitArray getFeistelResult(BitArray arrHalfBlock, int indexSubSleutel)
{
    BitArray Subkey = lijstSubkeys[indexSubSleutel];
    BitArray XoredHalfBlockAndSubkey = arrHalfBlock.Xor(Subkey);

    BitArray Result = Sboxen(XoredHalfBlockAndSubkey);

    return Result;
}
```

And the Sboxen function:

```
private BitArray Sboxen(BitArray array)
{
    List<int> lijsStartIndex = new List<int>();

    int sbox1Startindex = 5;
    int sbox2Startindex = 11;
    int sbox3Startindex = 17;
    int sbox4Startindex = 23;
    int sbox5Startindex = 29;
    int sbox6Startindex = 35;
    int sbox7Startindex = 41;
    int sbox8Startindex = 47;

    #region SBOXEN genereren
    //haal telkens de waarde uit de array van 48 bits en maak telkens een sbox ervan
    BitArray Sbox1 = GenerateSbox(array.Get(sbox1Startindex),
                                    array.Get(sbox1Startindex - 1),
                                    array.Get(sbox1Startindex - 2),
                                    array.Get(sbox1Startindex - 3),
                                    array.Get(sbox1Startindex - 4),
                                    array.Get(sbox1Startindex - 5));

    BitArray Sbox2 = GenerateSbox(array.Get(sbox2Startindex),
                                    array.Get(sbox2Startindex - 1),
                                    array.Get(sbox2Startindex - 2),
                                    array.Get(sbox2Startindex - 3),
                                    array.Get(sbox2Startindex - 4),
                                    array.Get(sbox2Startindex - 5));

    BitArray Sbox3 = GenerateSbox(array.Get(sbox3Startindex),
                                    array.Get(sbox3Startindex - 1),
                                    array.Get(sbox3Startindex - 2),
                                    array.Get(sbox3Startindex - 3),
                                    array.Get(sbox3Startindex - 4),
                                    array.Get(sbox3Startindex - 5));

    BitArray Sbox4 = GenerateSbox(array.Get(sbox4Startindex),
                                    array.Get(sbox4Startindex - 1),
                                    array.Get(sbox4Startindex - 2),
                                    array.Get(sbox4Startindex - 3),
                                    array.Get(sbox4Startindex - 4),
                                    array.Get(sbox4Startindex - 5));

    BitArray Sbox5 = GenerateSbox(array.Get(sbox5Startindex),
                                    array.Get(sbox5Startindex - 1),
                                    array.Get(sbox5Startindex - 2),
                                    array.Get(sbox5Startindex - 3),
                                    array.Get(sbox5Startindex - 4),
                                    array.Get(sbox5Startindex - 5));

    BitArray Sbox6 = GenerateSbox(array.Get(sbox6Startindex),
                                    array.Get(sbox6Startindex - 1),
                                    array.Get(sbox6Startindex - 2),
                                    array.Get(sbox6Startindex - 3),
                                    array.Get(sbox6Startindex - 4),
                                    array.Get(sbox6Startindex - 5));

    BitArray Sbox7 = GenerateSbox(array.Get(sbox7Startindex),
                                    array.Get(sbox7Startindex - 1),
                                    array.Get(sbox7Startindex - 2),
                                    array.Get(sbox7Startindex - 3),
                                    array.Get(sbox7Startindex - 4),
                                    array.Get(sbox7Startindex - 5));

    BitArray Sbox8 = GenerateSbox(array.Get(sbox8Startindex),
                                    array.Get(sbox8Startindex - 1),
                                    array.Get(sbox8Startindex - 2),
                                    array.Get(sbox8Startindex - 3),
                                    array.Get(sbox8Startindex - 4),
                                    array.Get(sbox8Startindex - 5));
    #endregion SBOXEN genereren

    //deze functie gaat de int waarde ophalen uit Arrays.SBoxArrays
    BitArray sbox1Value = new BitArray(getValueFromSbox(Sbox1, 0));
    BitArray sbox2Value = new BitArray(getValueFromSbox(Sbox2, 1));
    BitArray sbox3Value = new BitArray(getValueFromSbox(Sbox3, 2));
    BitArray sbox4Value = new BitArray(getValueFromSbox(Sbox4, 3));
    BitArray sbox5Value = new BitArray(getValueFromSbox(Sbox5, 4));
    BitArray sbox6Value = new BitArray(getValueFromSbox(Sbox6, 5));
    BitArray sbox7Value = new BitArray(getValueFromSbox(Sbox7, 6));
    BitArray sbox8Value = new BitArray(getValueFromSbox(Sbox8, 7));

    bool[] CombinedSboxen = new bool[32];

    sbox1Value.CopyTo(CombinedSboxen, 0);
    sbox2Value.CopyTo(CombinedSboxen, 4);
    sbox3Value.CopyTo(CombinedSboxen, 8);
    sbox4Value.CopyTo(CombinedSboxen, 12);
    sbox5Value.CopyTo(CombinedSboxen, 16);
    sbox6Value.CopyTo(CombinedSboxen, 20);
    sbox7Value.CopyTo(CombinedSboxen, 24);
    sbox8Value.CopyTo(CombinedSboxen, 28);

    return Arrays.SBoxPremutatie(CombinedSboxen);
}
```

And here's the getValueFromSbox function:

```
private BitArray getValueFromSbox(BitArray array, int WichSbox)
{
    BitArray arrayRow = new BitArray(2);
    BitArray arrayColumn = new BitArray(4);

    arrayRow.Set(0, array.Get(0)); //de eerste en de laatste bit nemen voor de rij
    arrayRow.Set(1, array.Get(5));

    arrayColumn.Set(0, array.Get(1)); //de overige 4 bits voor de kolom
    arrayColumn.Set(1, array.Get(2));
    arrayColumn.Set(2, array.Get(3));
    arrayColumn.Set(3, array.Get(4));

    int Row = CalculateToInteger(Arrays.ReverseBitArray(arrayRow)); //lengte 2
    int column = CalculateToInteger(Arrays.ReverseBitArray(arrayColumn)); // lengte 4

    Byte b = Arrays.SBoxArrays[WichSbox, Row, column];

    BitArray bit = new BitArray(BitConverter.GetBytes(b).ToArray());

    BitArray SboxValue = new BitArray(4);

    SboxValue.Set(0, bit.Get(3));
    SboxValue.Set(1, bit.Get(2));
    SboxValue.Set(2, bit.Get(1));
    SboxValue.Set(3, bit.Get(0));

    return SboxValue;
}
```

And finally the CalculateToInteger function:

```
    private int CalculateToInteger(BitArray array)
    {
        double result = 0;
        for (int counter = 0; counter < array.Count; counter++)
        {
            if (array[array.Length - 1 - counter] == true)
                result += Math.Pow(2, counter);
        }

        return Convert.ToInt32(result);
    }
```

EDIT:
Encryption of `0000 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 1000 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110 1111` leads to `10000101 11101000 00010011 01010100 00001111 00001010 10110100 00000101` after encryption which is what I want,

When encryption the 8 byte string `Testjeuh` I get `Ô§”\YDÕ¸` as a result which is not what I want.

Comment: DES is not secure. `</unhelpful>`

Comment: I know but this code will never be used for anything important or sensitive.

Comment: Did you check what is the encoding of that `string`? `string` to `byte[]` conversion is more complex than you imagine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't exatly an answer, but write some unit tests (I know I'm abusing that word).  Your first test should be something like:

```
BitArray inputData = BitarrayFromRandomData();
var encryptedBits = DesEncryptor.Encrypt(inputData, key);
BitArray outputData = DesEncryptor.Decrypt(outputData, key);
```

If the content of `outputData` match the content of `inputData` the problem is not in the DES implementation.  The next test is to look at the code that transforms between bytes and bits

```
byte[] inputData = ByteArrayFromRandomData();
BitArray intermediateData = BitarrayHelpers.FromByteArray(inputData);
byte[] outputData = BitArrayHelpers.ToByteArray(intermediateData);
```

Notice how there is no encryption step here, because we already ruled that out in the first test.  Write a similar test for your conversion between strings and byte arrays and a final test that covers the whole thing, once the first three pass the final one should also pass.

This will allow you to focus your attention (and SO questions) on just the code that is broken, rather than the entire DES implementation.

Comment: Thanks, this got me thinking about it.
I've been trying so many reverses of byte arrays and bitarrays that I forgot how text would be read. Removing them and adding one fixed my problem. Thanks